# Profiling Entity Framework Core using SQL Server Profiler

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, sql-server-profiler

When you look at the SQL Server Profiler when profiling Entity Framework LINQ statements, there are lot of events that's getting fired. To optimize the LINQ queries, what events should I monitor in profiler?

I figured `SQL:BatchCompleted` and and `RPC:Completed` to be actual queries that get executed but what is the difference?

[image]

Comment: Well you want to know 1) the statements it's generating for you and 2) what their query plans are. Truth be told, I don't know how much you can actually optimize using LINQ alone, but events which give you either or both of those would be where I would start

Comment: @Xedni What's the difference between SQL:BatchCompleted and RPC:Completed? should I worry about SQL:BatchCompleted queries?

Answer (score 0):

`RPC:Completed` is completion of a Remote procedure call, which means a stored procedure was called from an external application. EF Core in your case is calling the `sp_executesql` stored procedure to execute the SQL generated from LINQ queries.

`SQL:BatchCompleted` means a set of SQL statements have been executed. It can be a set of DDL or DML statements, or stored procedure calls.

Comment: Should I worry about optimizing performance if I see set of SQL:BatchCompleted events been executed when running a query from client app? i see few SQL:BatchCompleted events with select statements without any Where clauses.

Answer (score 0):

> I figured SQL:BatchCompleted and and RPC:Completed to be actual
>   queries that get executed but what is the difference?

The `SQL:BatchCompleted` event indicates an ad-hoc (not parameterized) batch of one or more statements completed execution. The `RPC:Completed` completed event fires when a remote procedure call request completes execution, which can be a parameterized SQL statement or direct stored procedure call.

EF uses the SqlClient API to execute parameterized queries. SqlClient uses the special `sp_executesql` stored procedure to execute parameterized queries so that is what appears in the trace. Profiler shows the deserialized request as `exec sp_executesql N'...`, including parameter values as text. The actual parameters are sent to SQL in native (binary) format.

These events are included in the standard Profiler trace template along with other events that capture logins, logouts. Note that when you see the sequence of events Audit Logout, 'sp_reset_connection`, and Audit Login, those occur when the first query is executed on a reused pooled connection and were triggered by the subsequent RPC for the same session you see in the trace. Those are all internal on the server side, not as a result of separate requests sent from the client.

**EDIT:**

I see you have a query-optimization tag in your question. To troubleshoot performance of problem queries, you could execute a captured request using SQL Server Management Studio with the view actual execution plan option. You could also capture the plan in the trace by adding the `Showplan XML` event, but should do that only on a dev box with a filtered trace to avoid overhead and impacting a production workload. An unfiltered Profile trace in production is bad.

Comment: Should I worry about optimizing performance if I see set of SQL:BatchCompleted events been executed when running a query from client app? i see few SQL:BatchCompleted events with select statements without any Where clauses.

Comment: It depends why there is no where clause. If it's loading a Country entity for a drop-down list, that would be expected (although should probably be cached for later use). But if it's a large result being filtered on the client due to a bad LINQ expression, that needs to be investigated.